# Does race affect damage, assuming otherwise identical weapons and combat skills?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If my opening questions answer is "yes", then wouldn't the +5/+10 skill bonuses races receive only be beneficial at the start of the game?

I know the races have individual racial abilities, but most of them are not that great. For every one of the racial abilities, you can get a spell or potion to do the same, *except* for the +50 magicka the High Elf has. You could have some enchanted armor and/or a potion to increase magicka, but a High Elf could do that plus have its racial +50 on top.

Is this correct? (And wouldn't this make High Elves the best race?)

Comment: Hello Chris, and welcome to Gaming.SE! Unfortunately, you seem to be a little confused bout what our site is. Gaming.SE is a Q&A site, not a forum. Therefore we focus on asking questions about problems you face with real answers, whereas your question seems to be more focused on starting a discussion, which is considered off-topic on our site. If you could modify your answer to turn it into a question, that would be great, otherwise your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you're correct, though you're overstating just how big a deal 50 Magicka is. It's one of the better racial bonuses, to be sure, but it doesn't completely outclass, for instance, 25% Magic Resistance or 50% Poison and Disease resistance.

Comment: Yeah that is true, I'm actually playing as a Breton because i liked the sound of 25% magic resistance and also the Dragonskin racial ability which absorbs 50% of magicka from hostile spells for 60 seconds which will come in handy later in the game (i hope) when i find a hard spell casting enemy. I was just think to max stats- Altmer would be best, with all enchanted armor, rings, neckless etc for magica plus altmers racial ability it would be awesome which all that magicka. But yes maybe 50 magicka doesn't mean much in the long run

Answer (score 1):

If you don't think the resistance advantages of other races are not significant, than yes, you're correct.

You're also right, that the skill bonuses effect do only give an early game advantage.

You're (likely, I can't prove it yet) **wrong**, that the High Elf could give you another perk if you maxed out every skill. You'll receive much more "exp" if you level up from 90 instead of 10. 10->11 **<** 90->91.